# Polymer prevent databinding

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, 2-way-object-databinding

Data binding is good, very good. But for once it is getting in my way.

I have a default array of `user`s that I insert in each `item` on my page. The idea is that each `item` has a checkbox for each `user`.

Currently I create my `emptyUsers`-item like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++){
    this.emptyUsers.push({"id": this.users[i].id, "set": false});
}
```

<sub>note: `this.users` is from the db</sub>

Then I push this array to every item on my page

```
item = {"id": data[i].itemId, "text": data[i].text, "users": this.emptyUsers};
```

<sub>note: `data` is from the db</sub>

The issue now is that when I change the `set`-attribute of one of the users in an item, the `set`-attribute gets changed for all items for that user. I presume this is due to data binding coming in to play somewhere since I use `push()` to insert the users in the item. Is this indeed the case, and how can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: When you are using an Array/Object and have initialized two-way data-binding, all elements will have the *same reference*. If you change the data, there is no way to stop the others from getting the change, if you want two-way data-binding on *that object*.

Comment: @FuzzicalLogic: so how can I prevent it then? I just need the array of `item`'s as data bound-objects, not also the users in the it'ms. (an item object has the structure `[{"id" : int, "text": string, "users": [{"id": int, "checked": bool}]}]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are giving each object a *reference* to the one `emptyUsers` array. If each object should have its own array from the start, you can create a copy when you first bind the data by calling `slice()` on `emptyUsers`. This will create only a shallow copy; if you need each object to also have their own copies of the elements in the array you should search for "js array deep copy":

```
item = {"id": data[i].itemId, "text": data[i].text, "users": this.emptyUsers.slice()};
```

Comment: The `slice()` still didn't fix the problem, but the deep copy provided by the link of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5344074/1319187) has a few methods that do seem to work. Thanks!